# Does anyone make low-profile ball lock disconnects?

Tags: kegging, corny-keg, kegerator

Is there such a thing as low-profile gas/liquid disconnects for ball lock corny kegs?  I'm curious if there's anything commercially available that is notably shorter in height than the typical black/gray plastic disconnects that are commonly available.  Since those direct the tubing at an upward angle, the total height of the disconnect plus tubing is around 3 inches, which can present challenges in height-constrained kegerator/keezer configurations.

Note: I did try googling for this, but the existence of low profile sankey keg disconnects makes that form of research challenging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the closest to "low profile" that I have seen.

http://www.morebeer.com/products/ball-lock-bev-stainless-flared.html
http://www.williamsbrewing.com/STAINLESS-STEEL-GAS-BALL-LOCK-BARBED-P3877.aspx

Comment: Thanks; if the heights stated on those pages (2 1/8" and 2 1/4", respectively) are correct, these are a substantial improvement over the 3" requirement of the plastic disconnects.